# Updating Location of Point Features using XY Fields?

Tags: arcpy, geometry, xy

I have changed the coordinates of couple points in the attribute table and I want to update the location. I have found the script that is working in field calculator.

Does anybody know how to write it using a Python script in ArcGIS Desktop (not in Field Calculator)?

```
def XYsetVALUE( shape, X_value, Y_value):
   point = shape.getPart(0)
   point.X = X_value
   point.Y = Y_value
   return point

__esri_field_calculator_splitter__
XYsetVALUE ( !SHAPE!, !X_COORD!, !Y_COORD! )
```

COORDINATE FIELD TYPE ------ STRING !!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [UpdateCursor](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) for this with the SHAPE@X and SHAPE@Y tokens. This will change the data so backup before executing:

```
import arcpy

feature_class=r'C:\Default.gdb\Points' #Change to match your data
fields=['X_coord','Y_coord'] #Change to match your column names containing x and y coordinates

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class,['SHAPE@X','SHAPE@Y']+fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0]=float(row[2])
        row[1]=float(row[3])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```