# Dynamically update points with xy coordinates in table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinates, oracle-dbms, point

I have an Oracle database table with columns for 'X' and 'Y' coordinates. Now I want to display these points in ArcMap. I can use the 'Display XY data' tool for that.

My table in the database with XY coordinates will be updated every day, so I have to update my points in ArcMap with the new coordinates, too.

Is there any way to automatically update my points in ArcMap based on my table in database?

Comment: Instead of relying on an event layer, you could add an SDE.ST_GEOMETRY or MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY column to the table, which would allow a spatial index and update of the geometry with a trigger, based on update of the X and Y columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can schedule arcpy to overwrite the existing featureclass/shapefile and re-create the points with [Make XY Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm)

be sure in the code to set `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`

schedule to run nightly, daily, hourly whatever meets your needs

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to create a python add-in extension for this that runs (when the extension is enabled) when a certain map document is opened calling the openDocument() function which has the Make XY Layer method/logic that @Geo.Dude suggested.  Each time the user opens a predefined (saved) map doc that has has a certain name (eg. map doc name "makeXY") it will check for this map name and if found will call the "make xy point" method within the openDocument() function.  For a python add-in tutorial of how to create this extension see:

[Creating a Python add-in application extension](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000018000000)

Here is a class example with the map name check:

```
class ExtensionClass1(object):
    """Implementation for test2_addin.extension2 (Extension)"""
    def __init__(self):
        # For performance considerations, please remove all unused methods in this class.
        self.enabled = True
    def openDocument(self):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  
        mapPath = mxd.filePath  
        fileName = os.path.basename(mapPath)
        if fileName == 'makeXY.mxd':
            # put Make XY Layer method/logic here
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your Python abilities you can update the shape values of your points using the `getValue` and `getPart` functions inside an `UpdateCursor`. If you want, I can edit this answer and provide some code that could help get you part way there (although my use case is a little different from yours in that I am updating locations in one layer based on coordinates in a 2nd layer using a field that is common to both). This is also very similar to what is being done at this link [Update the Location of a Point Feature and Its XY Fields](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252360/update-the-location-of-a-point-feature-and-its-xy-fields)