# Reverse direction of "Add Geometry Attributes" tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry

The ArcGIS Desktop tools [Add XY Coordinates](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-xy-coordinates.htm) and [Add Geometry Attributes](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm) read from [Shape] column and write the shape XY properties to new X and Y columns. I need to go the other direction, from X and Y columns to the [Shape] XY properties. It is a point feature class already, not a bare table.

[XY Table to Point](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/xy-table-to-point.htm) isn't applicable because creates a new feature class.

Comment: An alternative would be to just use the Field Calculator.

Comment: I've done this with points. I made an answer here but I didn't post the actual code for it. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278504/dynamically-update-points-with-xy-coordinates-in-table/278720#278720